# Equivalence of definitions of continuity

Tags: utility, preferences

One of the definitions of continuity is that the Upper Contour Set and the Lower Contour Set are closed.

I am trying to show that if preference is continuous and $x>y>z$, then there is some $\alpha \in [0,1]$ such that $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)z>y$

Can you help me to prove second one by using closeness?

Comment: Or you could do your own homework.

Comment: This is not my homework but I am also trying to find that. (my math is not good enough) But I can not find any kind of resource even similar to that idea.

Comment: I am also open to any kind of hints.

Comment: How come you are trying to find this proof? What motivates you to do it?

Comment: Hint: You can start by reminding yourself of the definition and characterizations of the closedness of a set.

Comment: I am studying temptation for my thesis. The paper that I am reading includes 3 types of continuity assumptions:(paper deals with menus, not singletons) USC, Lower vNM cont. and lower singleton continuity. I am trying to show that we may not need lower vNM continuity in some cases. This idea is not directly related to my thesis, but you can think that I am looking for ways to simplify my assumptions.
But in order to do that, first I want to learn about continuity with different definitions so that I can improve my understanding of continuity.

Comment: Best of luck to you then. IMO learning is thinking about unfamiliar concepts. As this question seems relatively simple it is a good exercise to solve by yourself.

Comment: You might consider if you can restate this such that it's purely mathematical.  Math.SE might be more open to such a question.

Comment: I am confused. Can you not set $\alpha = 1$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: it is easier if you go through the intermediate step that the set $\{\alpha \in[0,1]: \alpha x+(1-\alpha) z \succsim y\} $ is closed for every $x,y,z$

Answer (score 0):

I think a proof by contradiction would be easier (if your preferences are complete). If there is no such $\alpha$ then each $\alpha x + (1-\alpha)z$ is in the (weak) lower contour set of $y$, which is closed. Now construct a sequence (or net).